# how to call controller function from outside controller function like global function in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, cordova, extjs4, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can I call function which is inside controller from out side controller function like might be phone gap call back function

Here is the function defined out side the controller

```
  function onDeviceReady() {
    //do ALL your localstorage stuff here
    console.log('In onDeviceReady() function');
    somefunction();// this is not working
  }
```

Here is the controller class

```
     Ext.define('FCELB.controller.LoginController', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
        config: {
            refs: {
                username: '#username',
                password: '#password'
            },

            }

        },      

        init: function () {
            console.log('Login controller');
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            //onDeviceReady();
        },

        somefunction:function(){
            //some functionality
        }

   });
```

How to call `somefunction()` from the above onDeviceready() function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
FCELB.app.getController('LoginController').somefunction();
```

**Where**

FCELB - Application name

LoginController - Name of the controller

somefunction - Function name

Comment: This solution works but calls init function from the called Class everytime you run it.

Answer (score 1):

If your controller classes share some behaviour, you might also want to look at [ExtJS mixins](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-mixins)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.somefunction, false);
```

or

```
var self = this;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(e) { self.somefunction(e); }, false);
```